# Redirect rule in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to create the next rule in the .htaccess, but it does not work and I did not find the error. I want to move on from this:

https://www.miblog.com/2018/02/example-5.html

To

https://www.miblog.com/example-5/

I'm trying with this rule.

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/20(.*)/([0-9]{1,2})/([0-9]{1,2})/(.*)(/)?$ /$4
```

Comment: I've answer your question. As a plus advice I'll give you that site where you can always check your regex and see groups by color ;) https://regex101.com . Here you must escape also the '/' char so you have write '\/' instead of '/' like that: ^\/(20)([0-9]{1,2})\/([0-9]{1,2})\/(.*)\.(.*)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the job ;)

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(20)([0-9]{1,2})/([0-9]{1,2})/(.*)\.html$ /$4/
```

Or that

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(20)([0-9]{1,2})/([0-9]{1,2})/(.*)\.(.*)$ /$4/
```

Did you have `RewriteEngine on` right? :)

Comment: the first rule worked correctly. But if I analyze it in https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ it says not work.           If I use this rule RedirectMatch 301 ^([0-9]+)/[0-9]+/(.+)\.html$ $2, it says work on https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/, but it does not work on the web at the time of applying it.  Why did this happen?

Comment: @AlexanderGonzalez sorry, I didn't know this service. I never used it, so I couldn't tell you why it tell us a well formed rule it doesn't work .)

Comment: @AlexanderGonzalez remember what to do in this case https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers. ;)

Comment: One last query, when this code is implemented, there is a risk of losing traffic on the blog, or other adjustments or redirections must be made.

Comment: @AlexanderGonzalez only you as the site admin could know that. I mean you know with which urls your user may access your site. If you have old urls indexed on site crawlers (read: google) you must use rewrite rule to manage them accordingly to your policy. I suggest you look at apache log for 404 error in order to take care of them.  But this is another topic. See ya to the next question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(20)([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/(.*)\.html$ /$4/
```

**Note :** clear browser cache then test it .